# React Native command line 'processDebugGoogleServices' error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build an app with below build.gradle file but there is always one error failed to create folder. I have checked many answers but no one helped me in this.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Failed to create folder: D:\App\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug
```

my `app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-android-permissions')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
    compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':RNPermissionsModule')
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
        exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
    }
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0"
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0') {
        force = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you used google services plugin in classpath also?
If not please write in build.gradle located outside  of the app folder

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

I think this will help you ..!!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and I solved this by uninstalling the app `[yourapp.apk]` from your device (e.g: your mobile device) and then run `react-native run-android` again and it worked like a charm.

**But Why?**
because you've already had the app with the same name installed on your device (mainly because of the reason that you've downloaded it from somewhere -- and now you want to run the test.app which has the same name, so that's why you've faced this error

*do not hesitate to ask me any questions if it didn't work for you!*

Comment: I have tried your way but the issue is still the same :(